# mount failed /home partition for booting

Tags: linux, boot, xfs

I tried to change my `/home` username so I switch to `tty0` and change the username by `usermod` command but because some pid is active , I can't modify user. So I kill those proccess with `kill` command. After this I reboot my machine. Now for booting my machine, `/home` partition (XFS type) failed mount. So try fix that with

```
$ sudo xfs_repair /dev/sda5
print_req_error: IO error dev sda sector 1070323416
xfs_repair : Read failed input/output error
the log head and/or tail cannot discovered
```

Then:

```
$sudo xfs_repair -L  /dev/sda5
print_req_error: IO error dev sda sector 1070323416
xfs_repair: Read failed: Input/output error
zero_log cannot find log head_tail (xlog_find_tail=-5)
```

How can I resolve this to boot my machine correctly without lose of any data from the corrupted partition?

Comment: So from that I understand, you were able to get at least to single user mode. The `usermod` is unlikely to cause partition corruption by itself, there was probably some problem caused by something else. Please provide us outputs of `lsblk` and `fdisk -l`. Also check logs for related messages.

Comment: I run those and provide output below

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see, this looks like a problem with your disk, hence the I/O error.

If the partition is not too big, I would try copying it to a blank HDD with a rescue program like `ddrescue` and then try to repair it.